# JavaScript to change links on page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and am wondering how on a page with links to images, i.e. http://www.example.com/image.jpg I can get them to be changed automatically by JavaScript to be embedded, ie with `<img>` tag

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're particularly fond of the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) framework here, as it makes this sort of task very easy. With jQuery on your page, you can easily do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href$=.jpg]').each(function() {
        var imageSrc = $(this).attr('href');
        var img = $('<img />').attr('src', imageSrc);

        $(this).replaceWith(img);
    });
});
```

This will work specifically for `<a>` tags whose `href` attributes end with `.jpg` You can expand it to other file extensions, of course, but to dynamically determine whether a link leads to an image if the URL is not obvious would be a far greater challenge.

Comment: You're assuming he's using jQuery. You should preface which framework he would need to handle the syntax.

Comment: I'm not assuming jQuery, just recommending it (in the first sentence). I also included a link to the jQuery site.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Quickly, how would I then add an image width attribute to the tag as well?  Then I should understand the syntax!  Thank you.

Comment: How about `var img = $('<img />').attr('src', imageSrc).css('width', '400px')`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean convert all image url's to hyperlinks "pointing" to the images?

```
var x = document.getElementById('body');
x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(/(http:\/\/[^ ]+)/g,'<a
href="$1">$1</a>/');
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.  No third-party frameworks are needed.

From [here](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/590049-converting-urls-clickable-hyperlinks-using-javascript)